# How to calculate percentages in R Dataframe based on same value?

Tags: r

I have dataframe something like:

```
> myData

  User Similar
1  A     1
2  A     1
3  A     1
4  A     1
5  A     0
6  A     0
7  B     0
8  B     0
9  B     0
```

To something like this:

```
> myData

  User Similar Percentage
1  A      1    66.7%
2  A      0    33.3%
3  B      1    0%
4  B      0    100%
```

**Question**

I want to calculate percentages value **1** and **0** on column **similar** with specific user.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count` to count the frequencies for each `User` and then count the ratio.

```
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  mutate(Similar = factor(Similar)) %>%
  count(User, Similar, .drop = FALSE, name = 'Percentage') %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = Percentage/sum(Percentage) * 100)

#  User  Similar Percentage
#  <chr> <fct>        <dbl>
#1 A     0             33.3
#2 A     1             66.7
#3 B     0            100  
#4 B     1              0
```

---

In base R, use `table` with `prop.table` :

```
prop.table(table(myData), 1) * 100

# Similar
#User         0         1
#   A  33.33333  66.66667
#   B 100.00000   0.00000
```

**data**

```
myData <- structure(list(User = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B"), Similar = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i use count but the result is like using prob.table?

Comment: You can add `%>% pivot_wider(names_from = Similar, values_from = Percentage)` to the answer.